# How to get redux store to update dom of react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using react-testing-library to mount a react-redux connected component with my redux-store:

```
let comp = reduxRender(<ConnectedComponent />, {store});
```

reduxRender is a helper function that basically does this:

```
return {
    ...render(<Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>),
    store
}
```

I then dispatch an action to my store e.g.:

```
store.dispatch({type:'someAction'});
```

So my store updates correctly, however, the dom created by react-testing-library->render  does not update.  Does anyone know how to get it to update?
My goal here is obviously integration testing, I already have unit tests for each individual part of this lot.

Comment: which library do you use for your end to end testing? selenium or cypress?

Comment: I think that was a poor choice of words on my part. I meant integration testing. To have it tested from action to store to component render.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, it turns out there was something else wrong entirely here and has nothing to do with the question.  This setup was indeed working fine as is.